# pass revert to orderBy array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code:

jade (html)

```
ng-repeat="message in messageList | orderBy: [sortingByIsUnread, sortingBySentDate]
```

javascript

```
$scope.sortingBySentDate = function (message) () {
        return moment(message.sentDate).format('X')
}

$scope.sortingByIsUnread = function (message) () {
        return message.read
}
```

The above code works. But when passing an array to orderBy, is it possible to specify an order for a specific sorting method? (sortingBySentDate -> New dates on top)

Comment: How about `return -moment(message.sentDate).format('X')`?

Comment: I mean, if that works, should I turn the comment into an answer? )

Comment: yes you can, it was the only solution that worked for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, a sorting function maps a complex object to some simple value; these mapped values will be compared later on when the collection of those objects is ordered. Basically, if mapped value of `a` object is less than mapped value of `b` object, the former goes first.

As you basically compare timestamps (that's the result of `moment(message.sentDate).format('X')`), it's easy to revert their ordering - just negate the values with `unary minus` operation, like here:

```
$scope.reversedSortingBySentDate = function(message) {
    return -moment(message.sentDate).format('X');
}
```

That works, because for every 'regular' (non-NaN) number `a` and `b`, if `a < b` is true, then `-a > -b` is also true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes certainly, add a '-' to reverse the sort:

```
ng-repeat="message in messageList | orderBy: ['isUnread', '-sentDate']
```

Where isUnread and sentDate are properties of message.